# F# check if val member is uninitialized

Tags: f#, null, initialization

I have an F# class that uses the following to declare, but not initialize class members:

```
[<DefaultValue>] val mutable myVariable : myType
```

How can I check in the code whether this value has been initialized? I tried:

```
x.myVariable = null
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Wouldn't using something like `option` be more idiomatic in F#?

Comment: Yes. but I am asking nevertheless.

Comment: looks like `myType` here is a value type so it will not be null, you could compare against `Unchecked.defaultof<myType>` but there's a chance it could have been initialised to the default value so like @vcsjones says it would be good to use `option` here

Comment: Ok, so the reason I don't want to use an option is this: I am declaring it in an abstract class. I can't use let bindings because those would be private to the abstract class, and I need it to be accessible to the derived classes. I also need it to be a mutable so I can change its value, but I can't really make members mutable.

Comment: it wouldn't need to be a let binding or immutable: `[<DefaultValue>] val mutable myVariable : myType option`, then you can check if it's `None` to see if it's not initialised

Comment: Ok, I just realized that I could access the let bindings using members, so I suppose I can use options afterall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it is a bit hard to say what you are actually trying to achieve - using both uninitialized values and inheritance is generally not the preferred way of doing things in F# (but they are both sometimes necessary for interoperability with .NET), so if you follow this direction, you might not be getting that many advantages from using F#.

Wouldn't the following work for you instead? The idea is that we define a base class that takes the value of the private thing through a constructor:

```
type Base(myThing : Random) =
  member x.MyThing = myThing
```

And an inherited class can then provide a value, but also access it using a member:

```
type MySubclass() =
  inherit Base(new Random(0))
  member x.Next() = 
    x.MyThing.Next()
```